# I have a python django app that was working fine until Pylance was automatically installed. Now I get an error: Exception has occurred:

Tags: python, django

My code is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render         # Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import ListView   # <- new
from .models import Post

def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

And the error I receive is
from .models import Post
Exception has occurred: ImportError
attempted relative import with no known parent package

```
Post is defined in:
from django.db import models                         # Create your model fields here.
from django.utils import timezone                    # for the DateTimeZone field below
from django.contrib.auth.models import User          # the author field below needs this

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()                                 # TextField has no length limitation
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)     # Use the django timezone
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   # if the User is deleted, so will this model

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share the *full traceback* of the exception.

Comment: There is not traceback. When I open the project, error is the swiggly line under the Post which says it can't find the Post in the view.py. It is in the models.py file. The error is Class 'Post' has no 'objects' memberpylint(no-member).

Comment: This error relates to your pythonpath setup. You probably just need to configure vscode to add you django root directory to pythonpath. Possibly the pylance install changed some python settings, including this one.